# How to gain control of trackball in Nexus One Android

Tags: android, nexus-one, android-hardware

I'm kind of new in android AOSP development, and I'm trying to click to the trackball and launch an app already installed (Camera App).

I'm looking at the policy.androdoid, but i just doesn't understand how to gain controls of the hardware buttons and where to start.

Any help, source code example or something like that will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question but try looking here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

As for the starting [camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) look at the example [here](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)